# How to pass an argument included in '...' through to a recursive call in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am having trouble passing arguments through a recursive call to the `integrate` function.  Here is a simple example that illustrates my conundrum.

Consider a function, `foo1`, that requires a parameter `x` and returns some transformation of `x`.  For instance:

```
foo1 = function(x, alpha = 1.5) {
  return(x^alpha)
}
```

Now consider a function `foo2` that also requires `x` and returns some different transformation:

```
foo2 = function(x, y, z) {
  return(x * y * z)
}
```

Now consider a function `bar` that returns the finite integral (from `x` to `xMax`) of any `foo`-like function, but accepts a vector of multiple values for `x`:

```
bar = function(xVals, xMax, ..., fun) {
  return(
    sapply(
      xVals,
      function(xVal) integrate(f = fun, lower = xVal, upper = xMax, ...)$value)
  )
}
```

Note that `foo1`'s parameter `alpha` would be passed as part of the `...`:

```
bar(10:20, 100, alpha = 1.5, fun = foo1)
```

and `foo2`'s parameters `y` and `z` would also be passed as part of the `...`:

```
bar(10:20, 100, y = 2, z = 4, fun = foo2)
```

I like this arrangement because other required parameters for `integrate` can also be passed as part of `...`.  For instance, to change the default value of the `subdivisions` parameter of the `integrate` function called by `bar`, one can simply specify:

```
bar(10:20, 100, y = 2, z = 4, fun = foo2, subdivisions = 200L)
```

Now, consider a function that integrates `bar` from xStart to xEnd, but accepts vectors for multiple values for xStart and xEnd.  It might look like this:

```
integrateBar = function(xStart, xEnd, xMax, ..., fun) {
  aMatrix = cbind(xStart, xEnd)
  result =
    apply(
      aMatrix,
      1,
      function(xRange) integrate(bar, xRange[1], xRange[2], xMax, ..., fun = fun)$value
    )
  return(result)
}
```

So this is fine and pretty straightforward, until I want to call `integrateBar` but change the value of the `subdivisions` argument for the `integrate` function called within `bar`.  If I use:

```
integrateBar(10:20, 40, 100, alpha = 1.5, subdivisions = 200L, fun = foo1)
```

the `subdivisions` argument is grabbed and used by the `integrate` function in `integrateBar` and is not passed through to `bar`.  This is desirable behavior - sometimes.  But sometimes I also want to be able to leave `subdivisions` set at the default for the `integrate` call in `integrateBar` but change it for the `integrate` call in `bar`.  Can anyone tell me an elegant way to do the latter?

I'm willing to modify the formals for `bar`, but I'm trying not to make it too clunky because I want to call `bar` directly, too.  It would be really nice if there were some R trick so that a `subdivisions` argument would be ignored by the first integrate function encountered, but available to the second.

The best solution I have is to write a wrapper for `integrate` that uses a parameter `SUBDIVISIONS` and call the wrapper from `bar`.  If I don't get a better answer, I will post that solution.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `subdivisions` is not passed further from `integrate`, because it is an actual named argument of `integrate` (only arguments in `...`) will be passed to f:

```
> integrate
# function (f, lower, upper, ..., subdivisions = 100L, rel.tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, 
#    abs.tol = rel.tol, stop.on.error = TRUE, keep.xy = FALSE, 
#    aux = NULL)
```

One possible solution that does not require changing `bar` would be to write a wrapper for `bar` inside `integrateBar`. I have two variants:

Variant 1:
If you want to pass the arguments in `...` to both, the outer and the inner call to `integrate`, this would be it:

```
integrateBar = function(xStart, xEnd, xMax, ..., fun) {

    argsExtra <- list(...)

    # A wrapper function for bar:
    # Note that the argument ... is necessary, although the function does not use
    # it. This is because, we still pass ... to the call to integrate below. 
    CallBarOnFun <- function(xVals, xMax, ...) {
      do.call(bar, c(list(xVals, xMax), argsExtra, list(fun=fun)))
    }

    aMatrix = cbind(xStart, xEnd)
    result =
      apply(
        aMatrix,
        1,
        function(xRange) {
            integrate(CallBarOnFun, xRange[1], xRange[2], xMax, ...)$value
        } 
      )
    return(result)
}
```

Variant 2: If you want to pass the arguments in `...` only to the inner call:

```
integrateBar = function(xStart, xEnd, xMax, ..., fun) {
    argsExtra <- list(...)

    CallBarOnFun <- function(xVals, xMax) {
        do.call(bar, c(list(xVals, xMax), argsExtra, list(fun=fun)))
    }

    aMatrix = cbind(xStart, xEnd)
    result =
      apply(
         aMatrix,
         1,
         function(xRange) {
             integrate(CallBarOnFun, xRange[1], xRange[2], xMax)$value
         } 
       )
    return(result)
}
```